# Determining if $ I_n = \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi n}} \sin(t^2) dt $ is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If I define the sequence $I_n$:

$$ I_n = \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi n}} \sin(t^2) dt$$

Is this a Cauchy sequence? It appears to be, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it. Here is my attempt so far:

Assume that  $\epsilon > 0$ and $m,n \geq N \;(N\in\mathbb{N})$
$$ \left| \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi m}} \sin(t^2)dt - \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi n}} \sin(t^2)dt \right| < \epsilon $$

$$ \left| \int_{\sqrt{\pi n}}^{\sqrt{\pi m}} \sin(t^2)dt \right| < \epsilon$$

and I'm stuck here. Where can I go from this point? In addition, is the same true for $\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi n}} \cos(t^2)dt$?

Comment: $I_n$ converges to the convergent integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(t^2)dt$, so $I_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Would this suffice or do you want to prove it directly?

Comment: @Stefano Yeah I came across implication of convergence when researching the problem, however for education's sake I'd like to prove it directly.

Comment: Write $$I_n=\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}\,dt$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$I_n=\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}\,dt$$Then we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|I_n-I_m\right|&=\left|\int_{m\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}\,dt\,\right|\\\\
&=\frac12\,\left| \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt\,\right|
\end{align}$$

Then, note that for $t\in[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$, $\sin(t)$ is non-negative for even values of $k$ and non-positive for odd values of $k$.

Heuristically, for large $k$, we have

$$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{k\pi}}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sin(t)\,dt= (-1)^k\frac{2}{\sqrt{k\pi}}$$

Inasmuch as $\lim_{m,n\to \infty}\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k\pi}}=0$ (Leibniz's Test for alternating series), the sequence $I_n$ is indeed Cauchy.

Comment: I am not getting how we can replace $\sqrt{t}$ by $\sqrt{k\pi}$ , for large $k$?

Comment: For large $k$, $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}}\approx 1$.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: Ok that makes sense now!,It is amazing to see that for large $k$, $\sqrt{k} \approx \sqrt{k+1}$ and at the sametime it cannot be done for $\sin(t)$,since even for large $k$ , $\sin(k\pi)$ and $\sin((k+1)\pi)$ are of opposite signs!

Comment: Yes, and $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sin(t)\,dt=2(-1)^k$ too.  So, it's interesting that we can boil the problem down to an alternating series.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Mark's suggestion,

$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{n\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}\,dt $$
leads for sure to a Cauchy sequence, since $\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}$ is improperly Riemann-integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$ by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test): $\sin(x)$ is a function with a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ is decreasing to zero. As an alternative, you may just apply integration by parts:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi n}\frac{1-\cos(t)}{4t\sqrt{t}}\,dt $$
where the new integrand function is non-negative, behaves like $\sqrt{t}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin and decays like $\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t}}$ (that is an integrable function on $(1,+\infty)$) far from the origin.
Additionally, through the Laplace transform:
$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{N}\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{2\sqrt{\pi s}(1+s^2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^4}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}.$$
We have just computed a [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral). If $\sin$ is replaced by $\cos$, it is pretty much the same.

Comment: It is also possible to show that $$\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)-\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\right]$$ is a continuous and non-negative function on $[0,\pi]$, but that is not really easier than the approach by IBP.

Comment: I don't quite follow with the integration by parts. What does the behavior in a right neighborhood of the origin show?

Comment: @Dando18: take $1-\cos x$ as a primitive of $\sin(x)$, $-\frac{1}{2t\sqrt{t}}$ as the derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. The behaviour in a right neighbourhood of the origin shows that such a function is integrable there!